# How do I write an array-style initialiser for a class I wrote?

Tags: c#, arrays, constructor, indexing

In C# you can initialise arrays and other objects, such as Lists, or even Dictionaries, like this:

```
Type[] array = new Type[] { new Type(), new Type(), new Type()...};
```

or, more bizarre looking, for Dictionaries:

```
Dictionary<string, object> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object> () {
    { "key1", value },
    { "key2", value }
};
```

How would I write a constructor for my own type of object? In my case, I want to use it for an object I named `LayerGroup`:

```
LayerGroup layers = new LayerGroup() {
    "background",
    "foreground",
    "menu",
    "entities"
};
```

And I'd like to know how to do it in Dictionary style too:

```
LayerGroup layers = new LayerGroup() {
    { 4, "background" },
    { 1, "foreground" },
    { 0, "menu" },
    { 3, "entities" }
};
```

(In that case, I would of course have a different structure for the LayerGroup class, that's just an example)

Comment: Nothing changes, myClass[] newInstance = ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get collection initializer you'll need to implement 2 methods and inherit your class from `IEnumerable`:

```
public class LayerGroup: IEnumerable
{
    private readonly IList<string> _collection = new List<string>();

    public void Add(string value)
    {
        _collection.Add(value);
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _collection.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Similarly, if you want to get "Dictionary like" initialization, you need to implement

```
public void Add(string key, string value)
{
  ...
}
```

or whole `IDictionary` interface, if you want to get full spectrum of Dictionary functionality.

Answer (score 3):

The array-style initializers are called *Collection Initializers*. In order for collection initializers to work, the object being initialized needs to implement `IEnumerable`, and provide the corresponding `Add` method, with the signature matching the parameters that you plan to supply.

Hence the `LayerGroup` class needs to contain an `Add` method that looks like this:

```
public void Add(string name);
```

This would let you initialize `LayerGroup` with a list-like initializer. If you provide an `Add` method like this

```
public void Add(int number, string name);
```

you would be able to use a dictionary-like initializer (i.e. the last snippet from your question).

Comment: `LayerGroup` also needs to implement `IEnumerable`

Comment: Having that issue where two answers both give information that is useful and I don't know which to accept as the correct answer.  xD